# How to add padding between bars and axis in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to place images between the axis labels and the axis line or the bars in my case. Now it's a bit tricky because I don't have much space. I am restricted by the graph size and I have to work with the current dimensions. I tried the option of adding `tickPadding()` to the y-axis but that meant I went over the graph size and the labels were cut-off. is there a way I could move the bars to the right? or make the width a bit smaller?

[image: the current graph]

here is my code for the y-axis and the bars:

```
    let yScale_h = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, height])
      .padding(0.2);


    let xScale_h = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, width]);

    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
      .scale(yScale_h)
      .tickSize(0);

svg_bar.selectAll('rect')
      .data(dataset_performance, key)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr('width', function (d) { return xScale_h(d.Award); })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return yScale_h(d.clean_test); })
      .attr('height', yScale_h.bandwidth())
```

Comment: Could you please also add the code for the xScale and yScale? To move the bars to the right you can change the range of the x scale, but a full answer is more helpful if it considers the current implementation

Comment: That's actually what I am looking for I just changed the range max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to manually offset the bars to the right is to reduce the scale range, and add the padding to the 'x' property of the bars.

This example adds a padding of 20px:

```js
let xScale_h = d3.scaleLinear()

      .range([0, width - 20]); // Reduce the range by 20px

...

svg_bar.selectAll('rect')
      .data(dataset_performance, key)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr("class", "bar")

      .attr('x', 20) // Move bars to the right by 20px

      .attr('width', function (d) { return xScale_h(d.Award); })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return yScale_h(d.clean_test); })
      .attr('height', yScale_h.bandwidth())
```